# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when creating unit test - Jasmine (Angular)

Tags: karma-jasmine

I have unit tests with Jasmine and what I'm getting is this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

The actual code is this...

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.autoCompleteInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-input');

    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this));
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('input', this.onInput.bind(this));
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus.bind(this));

    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.inputRef.nativeElement, 'aria-autocomplete', 'both');
    if (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') {
      this.filter = '';
    }

  }
```

The first line of the addEventListener works

```
this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this));
```

but the remaining fail with **ng test --code-coverage --watch=false**

When I check the report I see this:

[image]

What I don't understand is why onBlur tests fine and the rest do not?

Here's my Jasmine code:

```
    import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
    import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
    import { AutocompleteComponent } from './autocomplete.component';
    import { filter } from 'lodash';

    describe('Auto Complete Component', () => {
        let autoCompleteComponent: AutocompleteComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<AutocompleteComponent>;
        let autoCompleteInput: HTMLInputElement;
        let filteredItems: string[] = [];
        let $window, $provide, listeners;
        // let rendered: DebugElement;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [
                    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
                ],
                declarations: [
                    AutocompleteComponent
                ],
                providers: [AutocompleteComponent],
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            }).compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutocompleteComponent);
                autoCompleteComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
                fixture.detectChanges();
            });

        }));

        it('should create call ngOnChanges ', () => {
            jasmine.createSpy('ngOnChanges').and.callThrough();
            autoCompleteComponent.ngOnChanges();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.ngOnChanges()).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should create filterItems() Function ', () => {
            jasmine.createSpy('filterItems').and.callThrough();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.filterItems).toBeUndefined();
        });

        it('should create call clearFocus ', () => {
            jasmine.createSpy('clearFocus').and.callThrough();
            autoCompleteComponent.clearFocus();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.clearFocus()).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should call onBlur Event ', () => {
            jasmine.createSpy('onBlur').and.callThrough();
            autoCompleteComponent.onBlur(event);
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.onBlur(event)).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should call onItemSelect Event ', () => {

            let item = '';

            jasmine.createSpy('onItemSelect').and.callThrough();
            jasmine.createSpy('clearFocus').and.callThrough();

            expect(autoCompleteComponent.onItemSelect(event, item)).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.itemSelect.emit(item)).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.clearFocus()).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

        it('should call onFocus Event ', () => {
            jasmine.createSpy('onFocus').and.callThrough();
            autoCompleteComponent.onFocus(event);
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.autoCompleteInput.focus()).toHaveBeenCalled;
            // expect(autoCompleteComponent.onFocus(event)).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should call onInput Event ', () => {

            jasmine.createSpy('onInput').and.callThrough();
            autoCompleteComponent.onInput(event);
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.onInput(event)).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation, I found the answer and I hope this helps others.

Here's the solution:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.autoCompleteInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-input');

    console.log('Add Event Listener: ', this.autoCompleteInput);

    this.bindOnBlurStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnInputStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback();

    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.autoCompleteInput, 'aria-autocomplete', 'both');
    if (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') {
      this.filter = '';
    }

  }

  public bindOnBlurStateEventCallback(): void {

    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this));
    document.querySelector('.search-input').addEventListener('blur', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
    });
  }
  
  public bindOnInputStateEventCallback(): void {
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('input', this.onInput.bind(this));
  }
  
  public bindOnFocusStateEventCallback(): void {
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus.bind(this));
  }
```

and in the spec.ts file:

```
    it('adds listener events', function () {
        spyOn(document, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();

        expect(document.addEventListener.prototype).not.toBeTruthy;
        expect(window.addEventListener.prototype).not.toBeTruthy;

        expect(document.addEventListener.prototype).toBeTruthy;
        expect(window.addEventListener.prototype).toBeTruthy;
    });
```

And there you have it!